# how to make getUserMedia() work on all browsers

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, webrtc

I learn about **web-rtc**, it says that you can capture video-cam ,
i used [demo](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/#toc-basic-demo) , well this worked on chrome only..

when i open it on firefox i get message `"getUserMedia() not supported in your browser."`
on another hand when  i open this [HTML5-rocks-demo](http://www.simpl.info/getusermedia/)

it worked 100%.
what changes or plugins or something i miss that let `getusermedia()` works.

Comment: To get this to work in IE and Safari, there are plugins, I haven't tried any of them, e.g. OpenWebRTC (sounds suboptimal but good for testing). An alternative if you only want to capture a single picture or video from the stream there is a description here, how to do it:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12811361/using-getusermedia-stream-api-with-ios-6   This would need some kind of browser-sensitive page handling.

Comment: FYI There is now a single function you can use: `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()` as per [the specs](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-main/getusermedia.html#legacy-interface-extensions):
*The official definition for the getUserMedia() method, and the one which developers are encouraged to use, is now at MediaDevices.*

Answer (score 29):

The issue is not just the prefixed function name; the stream provided works differently in different browsers. Here, I'll walk you through it.

I assume you've already set up a video element in the variable called `video`.

```
//I don't usually like to overwrite publicly accessible variables, but that's just me
var getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
var cameraStream;

getUserMedia.call(navigator, {
    video: true,
    audio: true //optional
}, function (stream) {
    /*
    Here's where you handle the stream differently. Chrome needs to convert the stream
    to an object URL, but Firefox's stream already is one.
    */
    if (window.webkitURL) {
        video.src = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(stream);
    } else {
        video.src = stream;
    }

    //save it for later
    cameraStream = stream;

    video.play();
});
```

This should cover you for Firefox, Chrome and Opera. IE and Safari don't support it yet.

Another potentially annoying thing to be aware of is how to turn off the camera if you want to stop using it before leaving the web page. Use this function:

```
function stopWebCam() {
    if (video) {
        video.pause();
        video.src = '';
        video.load();
    }

    if (cameraStream && cameraStream.stop) {
        cameraStream.stop();
    }
    stream = null;
}
```

Comment: Here is a chart showing browser support for this: http://caniuse.com/#feat=stream

Comment: I'm playing with this in Chrome console, and it only works if I provide a third parameter (the error callback) to the `getUserMedia` call.

Comment: Are there any updates to this answer? I read that we need to now use `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia`.

Comment: @navigator Yea, Firefox  was navigator.mozGetUserMedia and now is navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia

Comment: Just a update to you all guys, don't use ``video.src = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(stream); `` because it will give you error now, you can include direct stream like this ``video.src = stream;`` have a look here for more info https://stackoverflow.com/a/33759534/6110557

Answer (score 14):

Since Safari 11 is out, this works everywhere (tested on recent versions of Chrome, Firefox and Safari 11):

```
var constraints = {audio: false, video: true};
var video = document.querySelector("video");

function successCallback(stream) {
  video.srcObject = stream;
  video.play();
}

function errorCallback(error) {
  console.log("navigator.getUserMedia error: ", error);
}

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
  .then(successCallback)
  .catch(errorCallback);
```

Comment: This worked for me where `navigator.getUserMedia(constraints, successCallback, errorCallback);` failed on safari. Promise chains are nicer too.

Answer (score 9):

[**Fiddles**](https://jsfiddle.net/App7P/)

```
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;

var constraints = {audio: false, video: true};
var video = document.querySelector("video");

function successCallback(stream) {
  window.stream = stream; // stream available to console
  if (window.URL) {
    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
  } else {
    video.src = stream;
  }
}

function errorCallback(error){
  console.log("navigator.getUserMedia error: ", error);
}

navigator.getUserMedia(constraints, successCallback, errorCallback);
```

Comment: In Safari all three of these are undefined:  `navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;`

Comment: @RonWertlen i didn't check it on safari , but it worked fine on chrome & firefox, make sure you got latest version of safari,.

Comment: @RonWertlen Safari doesn't support it yet.

Answer (score 2):

`getUserMedia` needs to be prefixed with webkit- or moz-. The first example is only prefixed with webkit-. Therefor it will never work on Firexox, only Chrome and Safari.

The code example does not show the prefix...

Prefixing can be done in this way:

```
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
```

Comment: You could check how the other example have solved it. (Updated answer)

Comment: I have an example at http://simpl.info/gum that works in Firefox, Chrome and Opera.

Answer (score 2):

January 2021 - `navigate.getUserMedia` has been replaced with `navigate.mediaDevices.getUserMedia`

Answer (score 1):

```
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
```

In addition, you have to use https instead of http, otherwise Safari for iPadOS won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I know is pain full sometimes. specially in Mac Safari latest browsers So here i have solutions for you.

```
// Check for WebRTC
if (!navigator.webkitGetUserMedia && !navigator.mozGetUserMedia && !navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
  alert('WebRTC is not available in your browser.');
}
console.log(navigator);
// navigator object will help you to understand all browsers.
// for Safari !navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia
```