# Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL':

Tags: javascript, createobject

Display Below error in Safari.

> Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided.

My Code is:

```
function createObjectURL(object) {
    return (window.URL) ? window.URL.createObjectURL(object) : window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(object);
}
```

This is my Code for image:

```
function myUploadOnChangeFunction() { 
    if (this.files.length) { 
       for (var i in this.files) { 
           if (this.files.hasOwnProperty(i)) { 
              var src = createObjectURL(this.files[i]); 
              var image = new Image(); 
              image.src = src; 
              imagSRC = src; 
              $('#img').attr('src', src); 
            }
       }           
   } 
}
```

Comment: Hi Hardik, what are you passing to your `createObjectURL(...)` function when you get that error?

Comment: object must be a File object or a Blob object to create a object URL for.see http://devdocs.io/dom/window.url.createobjecturl

Comment: This is my Code for image:                                  function myUploadOnChangeFunction() {
           if (this.files.length) {
                for (var i in this.files) {
                    if (this.files.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                        var src = createObjectURL(this.files[i]);
                        var image = new Image();
                        image.src = src;
                        imagSRC = src;
                        $('#img').attr('src', src);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

Comment: @HardikMansaraa Go ahead and edit that in to your question.

Comment: `window.URL.createObjectURL('broken')` throws an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided.`

Comment: I had the same problem because I was importing `JSZip.js` twice.

Comment: @yxf is right, I was getting this error because I was passing an `ArrayBuffer` instead of a `Blob`

Comment: using Vue.js, when I change `fetch(...).then((response) => response.blob()).then(function(blob){var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)})` to `fetch(...).then((response) => { response.blob()} ).then(function(blob){var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)})`, this error occurs. it should be `then((response) => { return response.blob()} )` or just `then((response) => response.blob() )`.

Answer (score 298):

I experienced the same error, when I passed raw data to `createObjectURL`:

```
window.URL.createObjectURL(data)
```

It has to be a `Blob`, `File` or `MediaSource` object, not data itself. This worked for me:

```
var binaryData = [];
binaryData.push(data);
window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(binaryData, {type: "application/zip"}))
```

Check also the MDN for more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL

---

**UPDATE**

Back in the day we could also use `createObjectURL()` method with MediaStream objects. This use has been dropped by the specs and by browsers.
If you need to set a MediaStream as the source of an HTMLMediaElement just attach the `MediaStream` object directly to the `srcObject` property of the HTMLMediaElement e.g. `<video>` element.

```
const mediaStream = new MediaStream();
const video = document.getElementById('video-player');
video.srcObject = mediaStream;
```

However, if you need to work with `MediaSource`, `Blob` or `File`, you still have to create a `blob://` URL with `URL.createObjectURL()` and assign it to `HTMLMediaElement.src`.

Read more details here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/srcObject

Comment: Hi.. What to do if I am dealing with "application/pdf" ? I am getting the same error on console when I am dealing with PDF file

Comment: @mimo I am using same code to download file. But two files are getting downloaded. One is correct file and one extra file with same name but failed status is getting downloaded. Do you have any idea why it is happening?

Comment: I'm confused with this comment, in MDN it discourages the use of `URL.createObjectURL()` for media streams. However it doesn't state NOT to use it for a file input as stated in the initial question.

Answer (score 191):

This error is caused because the function `createObjectURL` no longer accepts media stream object for Google Chrome

I changed this:

```
video.src=vendorUrl.createObjectURL(stream);
video.play();
```

to this:

```
video.srcObject=stream;
video.play();
```

This worked for me.

Comment: +1 See example with fallback https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/srcObject

Comment: createObjectURL is not deprecated as shown [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL#Browser_compatibility) but no longer accepts media stream object

Comment: This should be the answer.

Comment: there is one another problem video.play() seems to be restricted : DOMException: play() can only be initiated by a user gesture.

Comment: @user889030 that just means you can't open a webpage and expect the webcam stream to start. You have to let the user explicitly start the stream. Just use a button to start the stream

Comment: Sorry to downvote, but while this answer is correct, it does not answer the OP's question which was about files, not media streams.

Answer (score 37):

My code was broken because I was using a deprecated technique. It used to be this:

```
video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(localMediaStream);
video.play();
```

Then I replaced that with this:

```
video.srcObject = localMediaStream;
video.play();
```

That worked beautifully.

EDIT: Recently `localMediaStream` has been deprecated and replaced with `MediaStream`. The latest code looks like this:

```
video.srcObject = new MediaStream();
```

References:

1. Deprecated technique: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL
2. Modern deprecated technique: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/srcObject
3. Modern technique: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream

Answer (score 10):

Video with fall back:

```
try {
  video.srcObject = mediaSource;
} catch (error) {
  video.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);
}
video.play();
```

From:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/srcObject

Answer (score 9):

I had the same error for the MediaStream. The solution is set a stream to the srcObject.

From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL):

> Important: If you still have code that relies on createObjectURL() to
>   attach streams to media elements, you need to update your code to
>   simply set srcObject to the MediaStream directly.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that the keys provided in the loop do not refer to the index of the file.

```
for (var i in this.files) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

The output of the above code is:

```
0
length
item
```

But what was expected was:

```
0
1
2
etc...
```

Then the error occurs when the browser tries to execute, for example:

```
window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files["length"])
```

I suggest implementation based on the following code:

```
var files = this.files;
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    var file = files[i],
        src = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(file);
    ...
}
```

I hope this can help someone.

Greetings!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using ajax, it is possible to add the options `xhrFields: { responseType: 'blob' }`:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'yourURL',
  type: 'POST',
  data: yourData,
  xhrFields: { responseType: 'blob' },
  success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    let src = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using angular this tutorial will be helpful: [link](https://balramchavan.medium.com/capturing-camera-using-angular-5-2e177c68201f). However you will need to replace this line:

```
this.video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
```

with this, since createObjectURL() is deprecated on chrome for MediaStream.

```
this.video.srcObject = stream;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//my code was:

this._videoEl = videoEl;
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
            video : true
        }).then(stream => {
            this._videoEl.src = URL.createObjectURL(stream);
            this._videoEl.play();
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });

//and replace to this worked for me :

this._videoEl = videoEl;
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
            video : true
        }).then(stream => {
            this._videoEl.srcObject = stream;
            this._videoEl.play();
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer aligns with more recent MDN examples at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia which show `video.srcObject = mediaStream;` without using `URL.createObjectURL()`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried few things, but for me simply assigning stream to src worked.

```
video.srcObject=stream;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by checking if the object is null.
 `{object ? URL.createObjectURL(object) : "default.png"}`

This made me to conclude that the error occur when object is null.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery - I had to add:

```
    xhrFields: {
        responseType: 'blob'
    }
```

to `data:` of my request

Answer (score -12):

I fixed it bydownloading the latest version from
[GitHub](https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs)