# Access Chrome URL object in ember test

Tags: ember.js, ember-qunit

I am testing an ember component that will do a call to an external method that returns a promise and calls the createObjectURL from the URL object of the navigator:

```
    @fetch(@get 'self').then((blob) =>
      url = URL.createObjectURL blob
      @set 'url', url
    )
```

However, test will always return:

```
TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided.
```

I have tried to create a service and inject it, create an object and pass it to the **@subject()** method, but still. 
Is there any way to access the window.URL object of the **chrome** browser inside an ember test?

Answer (score 0):

I've just found an answer here: [Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL':](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27120757/failed-to-execute-createobjecturl-on-url)

I need to create a blob previously and then pass it to the **createObjectURL** function.