# Wakanda / 4DMobile: Present contents of BLOB to client

Tags: wakanda, 4d-database

There is a PDF in a BLOB field of a table in the 4Dv15 database that Wakanda is connected to. When I pull the BLOB from the field in a serverside script (in Wakanda), it is an object:

`{'size': 12915, 'type': 'application/octet-stream'}`

The PDF or binary data do not appear to be in the returned object. I want to deliver the PDF inside the BLOB to the client. Can you help me figure out how to do this?

Thank you

Edit: This is what I get when I try using the code:

`console.log(blob);
var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
window.open(objectUrl);`

[image]

Edit 2: This is the serverside code I am using to get the blob. I am just trying to get it to work here. There is only one record in the table and it has a PDF in the BLOB.

`var reportCollection = ds.ReportLog.all();
var blob = reportCollection[0].ReportBlob;`

The result of this code is the object seen above-- I see no evidence that 4D is returning the binary data of the BLOB but instead only the properties of that BLOB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a Wakanda [Request Handler](http://download.wakanda.org/Documentation/current/SSJS-HTTP-Request-Handlers-API-v4.pdf) you could use `sendChunkedData()`:

```
response.sendChunkedData(blob)
```

Or write the blob to a file on the server using `.copyTo()` from the [BLOB API](http://download.wakanda.org/Documentation/current/SSJS-BLOB-API-v4.pdf) and serve the file to the client:

```
var myFile = new File (outputFolder + filename) 
blob.copyTo(myFile)
```

---

Another option may be the [URL.createObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) static method which could be used like this:

```
var objectUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
window.open(objectUrl)
```

See also: [URL.revokeObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/revokeObjectURL)

Comment: Thank you for your reply Tim. I tried using the URL.createObjectURL but got this error (image of error in original post). The line above it is a console log of the BLOB returned from 4D.

Comment: @NAMS this may be related to your error: [Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL':](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33759534/5971390) - i updated my answer slightly.

Comment: I looked into that, thank you- I see that the solution in that post was to use the `new Blob()` constructor inside of the `createObjectURL()` function, but one thing that I am missing if I'd try to do this is the actual binary data. When I pull the data in the BLOB field using serverside javascript, it is an object with properties `size` and `type` - never do I actually get binary data from 4D. I am wondering if this is a source of my problem. I get the feeling that the data returned from 4D does not contain the binary data which I need. I edited my post with the SS code to get the blob.

Comment: Also, I wanted to mention that in troubleshooting, I deleted a different field from the table: an Object field. Doing this changed the error to `TypeError: Argument 1 is not valid for any of the 2-argument overloads of URL.createObjectURL.` For whatever reason, the presence of Object data in an Object field causes issues, like for example the data browser would not return any records. I am on Wakanda v10 still. It's bizarre that the presence of that other field would cause issues because you can create tables with Object fields in them in v10. Maybe I can't do BLOBs in v10 either?

Comment: What about using `.toString()` from the [Blob API](http://download.wakanda.org/Documentation/current/SSJS-BLOB-API-v4.pdf) to check the contents of your blob.

Comment: When I do `blob.toString()` on the serverside, I get an error object: 

`{ name: "Error", message: "Cannot convert text from stream using the source encoding", messages: Array(), 2 more}`

Comment: Hey Tim, I got it to work on the serverside. When trying to use the BLOB's `copyTo()` function, I was using it incorrectly. This allowed me to write it to a folder on the webserver, which I can then serve to the client. Ideally I wanted to serve the record's BLOB directly to the client but this works.

`var myFile = new File (outputFolder + filename) ;
blob.copyTo(myFile);`

Thank you for all your help.

Comment: @NAMS cool - i will update this answer to include that information.