# Preview Image before upload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table. Each row has one cell for image uploading. I want to display the preview. For this I wrote the code below:

```
var cell8 = row.insertCell(6);
var t8 = document.createElement("input");
t8.type = "file";
t8.id = "img" + index;
t8.name = "img" + index;

var a = document.getElementById('blah_img' + index + '');
a.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);
t8.onchange = a.src;
cell8.appendChild(t8);

var oImg = document.createElement("img");
oImg.setAttribute('src', 'noimg.png');
oImg.setAttribute('alt', 'your image');
oImg.setAttribute('height', '100');
oImg.setAttribute('width', '100');
oImg.id = "blah_img" + index;
cell8.appendChild(oImg);
```

While running it gives me an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined.

What's wrong in my code? Please help.

Comment: Which line is giving that error?

Comment: window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])

Comment: What is `this` intended to be a reference to? Try `t8.files[0]`

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, `this.files` is `undefined`. Thus it's giving the error.
Instead of `this.files[0]`, try `t8.files[0]`

[Chobi](https://github.com/jayankaghosh/chobi/) is an **Image Processing Library**, implemented in pure Javascript which I have designed to make such things easier. You could check that out too

Comment: This is so unrelated to the OP's problem it's borderline self-promoting spam.

Comment: I've edited my answer to contain a possible solution

Comment: While changing this to t8, it shows `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27120757/failed-to-execute-createobjecturl-on-url Check this out. It might be useful.