# How to reuse getter method in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have angular 8 application.

And I have a get method. But this method I want to use in several components.

So I made a service of the getter method. But then I get some errors.

So I have the getter method like this:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GetProfileImageUrl {
  profileImagefile: File;

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

 get profileImageUrlDefault() {
    return this.profileImagefile === null
      ? '/assets/placeholder.jpg'
      : this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(window.URL.createObjectURL(this.profileImagefile));
  }
}
```

and the component looks like this, where I inject the method:

```
constructor(
  
    private getImageUrl: GetProfileImageUrl
  ) {}


 get profileImageUrl() {
    return this.getImageUrl.profileImageUrlDefault;
  }
```

and the template looks like this:

```
<img [src]="profileImageUrl" width="147px" />
```

But then I get this error:

```
core.js:5871 ERROR TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided.
    at GetProfileImageUrl.get profileImageUrlDefault [as profileImageUrlDefault] (get-profile-image-url.ts:15)
    at ProfileInformationComponent.get profileImageUrl [as profileImageUrl] (profile-information.component.ts:86)
    at ProfileInformationComponent_Template (profile-information.component.html:3)
    at executeTemplate (core.js:11926)
    at refreshView (core.js:11773)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:13213)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.js:11504)
    at refreshView (core.js:11825)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:13213)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.js:11504)
```

So what I have to change?

Thank you

So the method is working if I define it directly in the component. But I want to reuse the method in several components.

So if I try it like this:

```
 profileImageUrlDefault() {
    return this.profileImagefile === null
      ? '/assets/placeholder.jpg'
      : this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(window.URL.createObjectURL(this.profileImagefile));
  }
```

and I call the method like this:

```
  get profileImageUrl() {
    return this.getImageUrl.profileImageUrlDefault;
  }
```

I get this error:

```
profileImageUrlDefault()%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.profileImagefile%20===%20null%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20:1 GET http://localhost:4200/profileImageUrlDefault()%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.profileImagefile%20===%20null%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20?%20%27/assets/placeholder.jpg%27%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20:%20this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(window.URL.createObjectURL(this.profileImagefile));%20%20%20%20} 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: This might help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27120757/failed-to-execute-createobjecturl-on-url

Comment: ? it works if I define the method directly in the component. But because I have several components that are using that method - it will duplicate the code. That is the point. The function works fine.

Comment: `profileImagefile` is undefined if you don't set the value later on, but you're checking it for null, so it tries to run `createObjectURL` on undefined, which is not a valid operation.

Comment: Ok. without  `get` accessor your service works fine. Now, it's another problem with the way you pass the file link. It's better to use an absolute path here like `/assets/placeholder.jpg'`

Comment: What i have to change then?

Comment: But a user can upload a image.So how I have to change it then?

Comment: That error appears to show the contents of the function, URL encoded. I think @ng-hobby is correct that you're better off using functions and calling them as such instead of property getters.

Comment: Yes, oke. But I have done that. I made it as a function. But then I get the error. I have written it in the post. So what I have to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is the soluition:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GetProfileImageUrl {
  compWindow: any;

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    this.compWindow = window;
  }

  profileImageUrlDefault(profileImagefile: File) {
    return profileImagefile == null
      ? '/assets/placeholder.jpg'
      : this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(this.compWindow.URL.createObjectURL(profileImagefile));
  }
}
```

and injecting in component:

```
  get profileImageUrl() {   
    return this.getImageUrl.profileImageUrlDefault(this.profileImagefile);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a shared service is a good practice. well done. But I think your problem is in the way of calling the `profileImageUrlDefault()` function in your component. You should try this:

**app.component.ts**

```js
 constructor(cprivate getImageUrl: GetProfileImageUrl) {}

 get profileImageUrl() {
    return this.getImageUrl.profileImageUrlDefault();
  }
```

Actually you missed `()` of your function call on `return this.getImageUrl.profileImageUrlDefault` statement.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But if I call it like a method: (), then I get this error: This expression is not callable because it is a 'get' accessor. Did you mean to use it without '()'?
  Type 'SafeUrl' has no call signatures.ts(6234)

Comment: Yes, You are right.I mean try the `profileImageUrlDefault` without `get` accessor.

Comment: yes, oke. But then the problem is this: profileImageUrlDefault()%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.profileImagefile%20===%20null%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20:1 GET http://localhost:4200/profileImageUrlDefault()%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.profileImagefile%20===%20null%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20?%20%27/assets/placeholder.jpg%27%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20:%20this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(window.URL.createObjectURL(this.profileImagefile));%20%20%20%20} 404 (Not Found)

Comment: So the method works if I do it directly in the component. But because several components are using that method. It is better to have on central place for it.

Comment: ? So what I have to change then?