# Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugin-file, cordova-plugin-camera

I'm trying to create an object URL for a freshly captured photo loaded from disk with `cordova-plugin-file`, but it seems like it's not a normal `window.File` instance:

```js
const CAMERA_OPTIONS = {
  quality: 50,
  destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
  encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
}

captureImage = function () {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(
      imageURI => resolveLocalFileSystemURL(imageURI, fileEntry => {
        fileEntry.file(f => {
          console.log(f instanceof Blob, f instanceof File) // false true

          resolve(URL.createObjectURL(f)) // Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided.
      }, reject),

      reject,
      CAMERA_OPTIONS
    )
  })
}
```

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File), I should be able to pass `f` to `createObjectURL()` as-is:

> A File object is a specific kind of Blob, and can be used in any context that a Blob can. In particular, FileReader, URL.createObjectURL(), createImageBitmap(), and XMLHttpRequest.send() accept both Blobs and Files.

> The File interface doesn't define any methods, but inherits methods from the Blob interface

But that's not the case.

Also note the console log - `f` is an instance of `File`, but not `Blob`. Strange.

I also tried to get the URL directly with `fileEntry.toURL()`, but URL produced in that case is pointing to my devserver address (like `http://192.168.X.X:8080/__cdvfile_cache__/photo-name.jpg`). Obviously, it's not valid and doesn't work.

Also tried stuff like `URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([f], { type: 'image/jpeg' }))` but never got a valid image I could just put into `img`'s `src`.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL':](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27120757/failed-to-execute-createobjecturl-on-url)

Comment: Hello Eric! No it doesn't