# HTML5 Play Selected Video File

Tags: javascript, mediastream

Greatly confused with the seemingly conflicting info out there.

I am trying to cobble together a bare-bones select file and play video player (for later streaming to a NodeJs server).

I am having great trouble getting the browser to playthe selected video.

The code is here:

```
<script>

function newVideo ()
{
  const mediaStream = new MediaStream();
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(mediaStream);
  var vplayer = document.getElementById('vplayer');
  var vfile = document.getElementById('videoFile');
  console.log(' vfile: ', vfile.files[0].name);
  source.src = mediaStream;
//  source.src = URL.createObjectURL(vfile.files[0].name);
//  source.parent().load();
}

</script>

<video width="400" controls>
  <source src="" id="vplayer">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>

<input type="file" name="file[]" id="videoFile"
       class="file_multi_video"
       onchange='newVideo();'
       accept="video/*">
```

When I run this, selecting a MP$ video file, I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': Overload resolution failed.
    at newVideo (video.html:7:19)
    at HTMLInputElement.onchange (video.html:23:114)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL':](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27120757/failed-to-execute-createobjecturl-on-url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create the URL for the `<source>` element using the file set in the input.

```js
function newVideo ()
{
  var vplayer = document.getElementById('vplayer');
  var vfile = document.getElementById('videoFile');
  console.log(' vfile: ', vfile.files[0].name);
  var source = document.createElement('source')
  source.src = URL.createObjectURL(vfile.files[0]);
  vplayer.replaceChildren(source);
}
```

```html
<video id="vplayer" width="400" controls></video>

<input type="file" name="file[]" id="videoFile"
       class="file_multi_video"
       onchange='newVideo();'
       accept="video/*">
```

Comment: Worked! Thank you. I am a bit confused as from what I read, MSE is the way to go these days. But I'm happy this is working now.

Answer (score 1):

To fix the error you can create a Blob from the selected file
thing like this ...

```
function newVideo() {
  const vplayer = document.getElementById('vplayer');
  const vfile = document.getElementById('videoFile');
  const file = vfile.files[0];
  
  if (file.type.indexOf('video') === -1) {
    console.log('صيغة الملف غير مدعومة');
    return;
  }
  
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function() {
    const blob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(reader.result)]);
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    vplayer.src = url;
    vplayer.play();
  };
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
}
```

Comment: This didn't quite work, but thank you very much for this as it gives some useful pointers.