# error 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': Overload resolution failed typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

problem:when i try this code the page turn blank and the console show error like this

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': Overload resolution failed.
> [error from console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pu5rt.png)

this is the code

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./index.css";

import ImageModal from "../Cropper/imageModal";

const ImageInput = ({
  name,
  onChange,
  showPreview,
  imageData,
  defaultPic,
  type,
  label
}: {
  name: any;
  onChange: any;
  showPreview: any;
  imageData: any;
  defaultPic: any;
  type:any;
  label:any
}) => {
  const [image, setImage] = useState("");
  const [modalIsOpen, setModalIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const [height, setHeight] = useState<number | null>(null); 
  const [width, setWidth] = useState<number | null>(null); 

  const onChangeHandler = (file: File) => {
    onChange({
      [name]: {
        data: file,
        src: URL.createObjectURL(file),
      },
    });
  };

  const handleFile = (e:any) => {
    if (e.target.files.length > 0) {
      const file = e.target.files;
      var url = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.target.files[0]);
      var img = new Image();
      img.src = url;
      img.addEventListener('load', function() {
        console.log(this.width + 'x' + this.height);
      })
  
      const maxAllowedSize = 5 * 1024 * 1024;
      if (file[0].size > maxAllowedSize) {
        console.log("max image size");
      } else {
          setImage(file[0]);
          setModalIsOpen(true);
      }
      e.target.value = null;
    }
  };
  let inputElement:any;
  return (
    <>
      <ImageModal
        modalIsOpen={modalIsOpen}
        closeModal={() => {
          setModalIsOpen((prevState) => !prevState);
        }}
        image={image}
        onCropImage={(croppedImg: File) => onChangeHandler(croppedImg)}
        ratio={height && width ? height / width <= 0.5 : false}
      />
      {showPreview && (
        <div>
          <img
            key={imageData}
            src={imageData ? URL.createObjectURL(imageData) : defaultPic}
            className={imageData ? "company-logo" : "default-company-logo"}
            alt="img"
            onError={(e) => (e.target as HTMLImageElement).src = defaultPic}
          />
        </div>
      )}
      <div className={"upload-image"} onClick={() => inputElement.click()}>
        Upload
      </div>
      <input
        ref={(input) => (inputElement = input as HTMLInputElement)}
        accept="image/*"
        type="file"
        style={{ display: "none" }}
        onChange={handleFile}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default ImageInput;
```

question:
-how to solve error like that?

-what i need to change to add to solve the error?

Comment: does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27120757/failed-to-execute-createobjecturl-on-url?