# Why am I facing error Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' in handlePlay function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

```
  const handlePlay = (index) => {
    setCurrentTrackIndex(index);
    const audio = audioRef.current;
    const file = playlist[index];

    console.log("Selected file:", file);

    if (file) {
      try {
        const audioUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        console.log("Audio URL:", audioUrl);
        audio.src = audioUrl;
        audio.load();
        audio.play();
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error playing audio:", error);
      }
    } else {
      console.error("Invalid file:", file);
    }
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <input type="file" accept=".mp3" onChange={handleFileChange} />
      <div>
        {playlist.map((file, index) => (
          <div key={index}>
            <button onClick={() => handlePlay(index)}>{file.name}</button>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div>
        Now Playing: {playlist[currentTrackIndex]?.name}
      </div>
      <audio controls ref={audioRef} onEnded={handleEnded} />

    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

I am trying to build a webapp where when you click on audio, it plays the audio.
Upon clicking the audio button it console logs error "Error playing audio: TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': Overload resolution failed."
I expected it to play the audio.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL':](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27120757/failed-to-execute-createobjecturl-on-url)

Comment: @AndyRay I tried this 
`
  const handlePlay = (index) => {
    setCurrentTrackIndex(index);
    const audio = audioRef.current;
    const file = playlist[index];
    var binaryData = [];
    binaryData.push(file);
    const audioUrl = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(binaryData,{type:"application/audio"}));
    audio.src = audioUrl;
    audio.play();
  };
`
error : Failed to load because no supported source was found.