# Access mobile microphone with navigator.getUserMedia (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, android, microphone, web-audio-api

building an open source app, and I released the desktop version (dmeowmixer.github.io/voicetrainer) but when I load it in mobile (my phone uses android browser) and click the button to prompt for access to users microphone input it alerts that navigator.getUserMedia isn't supported. I read somewhere that it was supported in previous version of android browser but I'm not too sure. Could someone shed some light on if this will be possible to do in mobile without making a completely new application? 
https://github.com/Dmeowmixer/voiceTrainer link to repo

Comment: os it's not possible right?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly make sure that your android browser is supporting getusermedia. You could use the link below to check it out. http://caniuse.com/#feat=stream. If it is not supported on a browser, i don't think you can do much about it.

Check The stream provided works differently in different browsers answer to make sure you are doing the right thing [how to make getUserMedia() work on all browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21015847/how-to-make-getusermedia-work-on-all-browsers) if it is supportd by it!