# Select back camera on html5-qrcode.min.js

Tags: javascript, html, qr-code

I use this qr code scanner:
https://github.com/mebjas/html5-qrcode

I use this code to scan qr code:

```
         function onScanSuccess(decodedText, decodedResult) {
  // handle the scanned code as you like, for example:
  document.getElementById('text').value = decodedText;
  console.log(`Code matched = ${decodedText}`, decodedResult);
}

function onScanFailure(error) {
  // handle scan failure, usually better to ignore and keep scanning.
  // for example:
  console.warn(`Code scan error = ${error}`);
}

let html5QrcodeScanner = new Html5QrcodeScanner(
    "reader", { fps: 10, qrbox: 250 }, /* verbose= */ false);
html5QrcodeScanner.render(onScanSuccess, onScanFailure);
```

It is possible to set default camera to back smartfone camera. I want to run scanner with setted back camera on startup.
Thanks, for some help.

Comment: you'll probably need to use [navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/enumerateDevices)

Comment: How to use that  ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing device camera using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49473678/accessing-device-camera-using-javascript)

Comment: Did you notice it was a link to documentation, and in that documentation there are examples and other very helpful links to all the information you could ever want to *research*

Answer (score 5):

I accomplish it using this bit of code when I launch the scanner:

facingMode: { exact: "environment"}

Maybe this will help point you in the right direction. Below is the way the setting is used when I launch the scanner:

```
    /** load scanner using back camera **/
    html5QrCode.start({ facingMode: { exact: "environment"} }, config, qrCodeSuccessCallback);
```

Comment: (Code author here) The answer by @Rodney is correct.

Comment: On my Samsung S21, this defaults to the wide angle lens which doesn't have focus, small QR codes are impossible to scan like this.

Comment: As @user2924019 noticed, this not allows the selection of the camera if there are multiple back or front cameras on the device.
Does anyone know a way to select a specific camera ?

Answer (score 3):

```
const scanner = new Html5QrcodeScanner('reader', {
                qrbox: {
                    width: 200,
                    height: 200,
                },
                fps: 5,
                videoConstraints: {
                    facingMode: { exact: "environment" },
                },
            },
            false)
        scanner.render(success, error);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).